# Edit and Run jQuery in div multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making html/css/js editor. It must refresh and show the result while coding.

Made three textareas - for HTML, CSS and JS, and have such code:

```
$('#HTML, #CSS, #JS').keyup(function(){ 
   $('#resultDIV').html(
      '<script src=\'jQuery\'><\/script>' +
      '<style>' + $('#CSS').val() + '<\/style>' +
                  $('#HTML').val() +
      '<script>' + $('#JS').val() + '<\/script>'
   ); 
});
```

[Simple DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L70xnc3s/) (edit anything in textareas, and then click 'FOO')
HTML, CSS, JS - run correctly, but I got issue with jQuery - after any edit in any textarea - it runs again. And if there were 50 edits, 'click' event fires 50 clicks instead of 1. Is there any way to 'clean' all previous codes from memory and run only current code? `empty();` and `html('');` don't help.

I still have another way - each time empty() the current result, and load a new window in div, with written code. But it seems to be too heavy...

Comment: There is no click event logic in the question.  Only `keyup`

Comment: If you are trying to build something like jsfiddle or pastebin, then you should examine how they approach this.  They create dummy iframes that they write the code into.  Any time the code changes, the iframe is blown away, and a new one created and written to, so it is sandboxed.

Comment: the last time i tried something like this, i generated a file that would link to the JS and CSS as separate files.  But with each update, the "external" files would get an increasing token assigned to it (to help "clear" things out and discourage browser cache) sample.js?counter=123

Comment: I think a couple of the online tools available will also run the JS somewhere to make sure that a infinite code isn't accidentally being executed ... not too certain on how to pull that off, off the top of my head :)

Comment: @Taplar , I mean a possible user-code in JS-textarea - with click events. If click must add +10 to some value, and user have edited the code 50 times - each click adds +500 instead of +10.

Comment: Please refer to my statement about using an iframe to sandbox the logic.  If the javascript that is being dynamically ran is creating bindings on any part of the DOM, then if you do not want them to happen also on the second run, you will have to keep track of what bindings you make, and remove them.  Otherwise your script is allowing for the creation of duplicate bindings.

Comment: `$(document).on('click','#foo'` is creating a delegate event handler outside of the div, on the document.  If you do not want that to re-run every time the scripts are re-executed, you are going to have to `off()` that event handler on the document

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [@Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar) in comments, you can wrap your render in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). Each edit will delete your iframe and recreate a new one.

Another solution (not tested) could be to unreference all your event listeners with [`$.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) before readding your HTML:

```
$('#resultDiv *').off();

$('#resultDIV').html(
      '<script src=\'jQuery\'><\/script>' +
      '<style>' + $('#CSS').val() + '<\/style>' +
                  $('#HTML').val() +
      '<script>' + $('#JS').val() + '<\/script>'
);
```

The example above shows only for event listeners, but you may encounter many problems with variable declarations too.

Comment: This only works if the bindings are on children of the div, and if the bindings were added with jQuery, and not `addEventListener()`

Comment: And actually, given that the entire contents of the div are being replaced, this would lean more towards `off()` not working.  Destroying all the previous children would remove all binding assigned on them.  So the script is creating bindings on things not in the div.

Comment: You are right. It is not a good way to do what he wants to do, the user-input javascript could alters the page dom.

Comment: I thought that listeners would be automatically reassigned if you use `$(document).on('click', '.myclass', () => { ... });` even if you replaced all the html. I may be wrong however.

Comment: No, that binding is creating a delegate event handler on the document, which is an (indirect) parent of the div.